# UIImage и форма (SKSpriteNode)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Мне необходимо обрезать UIImage по примеру картинки которая естьКаким-то образом это можно сделать через SKSpriteNode но прочитанные гайды не дали мне ответа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вам надо обрезать картинку по маске? зачем эта звездочка в вопросе?

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko по этой звезде мне нужно обрезать картинку. Она служит маской. И таких с десяток разных...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Вот такой туториал](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html#comment-47347) нашел по этой теме.

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```